# Flex box - overflow issue when warp

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, word-wrap

Let's me try to explain the issue.

Assume we have 2 flex box `boxOrange` and `boxPurpule` who share the full width of a container and stretch to the height of this one. Due to their `min-width` of `400px`, these flex box warp in 'column' on small screen (demonstration in Example 1).

If one of the box contain too much content, the box is scrollable (like `boxOrange` in the demonstration of Example 2).

The issue is when their is scrollable content on small screen. I would like the `boxOrange` keep `50% height` of `container` when it warp. As you can see in Exemple 2, the content of `boxOrange`, isn't scrollable and overflow the `container`.

Do you know how to fix that ?

## Example 1  - [Available on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/zboule/pen/WwJbQd?editors=1100)

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#boxOrange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#boxPurple {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>

  <div id="boxOrange">

  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>

</div>
```

## Example 2  - [Available on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/zboule/pen/JXvjwV?editors=1100)

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#boxOrange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#boxPurple {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="boxOrange">
    CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the `boxOrange` a `max-height: 50%` it will scroll instead of grow

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#boxOrange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#boxPurple {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  #boxOrange {
    max-height: 50%;
  }
  #boxPurple {
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="boxOrange">
   CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this, how to have a stretch height (to 100%) before warping ?

Comment: Auxiliary question - in you exemple, how to remove the space betwen orange and purple block ?

Comment: @JordaneCURE Updated my answer, where instead of wrap rows, I changed it to `flex-direction: column;` and removed `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: I also try to update the description of the question to make it more precise.

Comment: In big screen, i would like both container stay each other with `flex-direction: row;` and use a height of 100% with `align-items: stretch ;`    . When the `width` of the container is too small to fit with the contraint `min-width`of the 2 box, the layout warp the `boxPurple` under the `boxOrange`.

Comment: @JordaneCURE Updated it again. The media query needs some adjustments but that's how you solve this issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it's a solution to solve the issue. But with media querry we loose some benefits of flex box.

Comment: For example, if we talk about the layout of a module that will be insert in any kind of page template, we don't know how much % of the `screen width` the `container` will use. So we can't know the brake point to use in the media query to match the flexbox warp.

Comment: @JordaneCURE No you don't, as `flexbox` doesn't replace media queries.

Comment: @JordaneCURE If that's the case you need script, and `flexbox` doesn't replace scripting either. Note that `flexbox` is not some magic that can do everything.

Comment: @JordaneCURE My answer solve your question and the now additional requirements in your comments needs to be posted in a new question as they require a completely different answer. Please accept this answer and post a new question with new requirements.

Comment: I know that i can also use JS to do what i want, but i hope their is a 'pure' flex solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the media query proposed by @LGSon.

This solution is in JS (with jQuery), it's nice if the breakpoint is unknown

```js
/* Modify layout */
jQuery(function($){
    
    var boxOrange = $("#boxOrange");
    var boxPurple = $("#boxPurple");
    
    var breakPoint  = parseInt(boxOrange.css('min-width')) + parseInt(boxPurple.css('min-width'));

    var container = $("#container");
        
        
    $(window).load(function(){
        setRowOrColumn();
        $(window).resize(setRowOrColumn);
   });
 
 
    function setRowOrColumn ()
    {
      if (container.width() < breakPoint && container.hasClass( "in_row" ))
      {
        container.removeClass("in_row");
        container.addClass("in_column");
      }
      else if (container.width() >= breakPoint && container.hasClass( "in_column" ))
      {
        container.removeClass("in_column");
        container.addClass("in_row");            
      }
    }
 
});
```

```css
#container
{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  
  display: flex;
}

#container.in_row
{
  flex-direction:row;
}

#container.in_column
{
  flex-direction:column;
}

#boxOrange
{
  background-color:orange;
  flex:1;
  min-width:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

#boxPurple
{
  background-color:purple;
  flex:1;
  min-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container class="in_row">
  <div id="boxOrange">
    CONTENT -  CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT 
  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>
</div>
```