# Why content overflow after row flexbox wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, warp

In the following example, could you explain why`boxOrange` content overflow when `boxPurple` wrap under `boxOrange` ?

Some solution to fix the issue with media query or JS have been found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652439/flex-box-overflow-issue-when-warp)

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#boxOrange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  min-width: 400px;
}
#boxPurple {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="boxOrange">
    CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did it work? or is it not what you are looking for?

Comment: I find some solution to fix it with Javascript. But i would like to understand why it's overflow when it's warp (but not overflow before warp)

Comment: it is always overflow the way i showed you! and in my answer i explain why

Answer (score 0):

just glancing at it, try setting a max-height for #boxOrange

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for??

you have to give the container `min-height:300;` and to the `boxOrange` and `boxPurple` `height:300px;` and if you put `overflow: auto;` you will have the scrollbar only on the side!

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#boxOrange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 400px;
 height:300px;
}
#boxPurple {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 2;
  min-width: 400px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="boxOrange">
    CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
    - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
  </div>

  <div id="boxPurple">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That almost that, but the goal is to keep the height of `container` div before and after the warp.

Comment: We have find some solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652439/flex-box-overflow-issue-when-warp/36655490#36655490)

Comment: I ask the question to understand why the container overflow after the warp.